# dimension of projective modules over KG-algebra

Tags: representation-theory

In Aleprin's book "Local Representation Theory" on page 33 the Corollary 7 says:
" If a Sylow p-subgroup P of the group G has order p^a then every projective KG-module has dimension divisible by p^a". I don't understand does he mean by dimension in that case? He means the dimension as a KG-module or as a vector space over K?

Comment: Since $K[G]$ is a projective module that has rank 1 over $K[G]$, it's most likely the dimension over $K$.

Comment: I do believe the same, but in that book he mentioned in other cases the notion of dimension as well meaning the dimension (rank) of a KG-module, instead of the dimension as a vector space. Also the proof is somehow non understandable.